# Track Accelerometer under lock screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, tracking, accelerometer

Is it possible to track the accelerometer value while under the lock screen?

I managed to write a simple application which counts from 1 up to 100 using a timer which fires an event on which I increment a counter.

But when I use register a handler for the ReadingChanged event of the accelerometer it will not be fired anymore once the screen has been locked. Even if I unlock the screen again I will have to readd my handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the msdn documentation tells on the one page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090(v=vs.105).aspx
"Valid reasons to disable idle detection in Windows Phone OS 7.1 applications include ones where core functionality continues while the phone is locked (for instance, an exercise tracking app)"

but the sensor api also tells:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202968(v=vs.105).aspx

"The Sensor APIs cannot be used while the application is running under the lock screen. For more information, see Idle Detection for Windows Phone. The Sensor APIs also cannot be used in background agents. For more information, see Background Agents Overview for Windows Phone"

I hope they will change the api soon, because of that it is not possible to write any good sleep tracking / sport tracking applications ... :(

Answer (score 1):

I was helping a guy with this a couple of days ago. He had an app that tracks GPS and accelerometer data under lock screen.

Turned out the app accelerometer data stopped tracking when under manual or auto lock screen.

There may be an issue here to be looked into.

Under lock screen it is a good idea to minimise power usage... disable all uncessary code, like ui updates. My understanding of one the motivations for idle detection and running under lockscreen being opened up during CTP was in response to a lot of feedback from developers of map/tracking apps that basically need this for their app to be of any use.

Comment: It's the same for me: I need the possibility to track movement under the lockscreen for my app to be of any use. It's a shame this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This has been acknowledged as a known issue since we last discussed this here. We should see an update to resolve this in due course.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure of the usage case where you'd want to use the accelerometer under the lock screen.

Apps typically run under the lock screen when you need them to do something when you're not interacting with the device. e.g. playing music or downloading a large file.

If you wanted accelerometer data I'd assume that the device is being held and, therefore, presumably, looked at. Given this, why would you therefore want to run under the lock screen?

That being said, if you had a good reason to do so, you should still be aware that:

> when your application runs under a locked screen, it ... must minimize
>   power usage

(from the [Marketplace Certification Requirements](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/D/12D67308-29EE-463D-A442-142F6982AECE/Windows%20Phone%207%20Application%20Certification%20Requirements.pdf).)

In my understanding, reading values from sensors is not minimizing power usage.

Comment: @crapper I can think of a bunch of reasons why the phone wouldn't be good for a pedometer. The most important being that constant triggering of the accelerometer will drain the battery really fast. Is this what you're building?

Comment: Matt is right. this is a lot of data, a lot of garbage, a lot of power. No idea if it pass cert.

Comment: No, this is not what I am building. It was just to give an example where using the accelerometer while the screen is locked would make sense.