# Accelerometer recording while screen is locked

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

hy!

I m writing the data that my accelerometer's acm_CurrentValueChanged gives me into a file, like this: X, Y, Z, time
and my app stops recording every time i lock the screen, how can i make the app to record **while the screen is locked**?

i tried to copy

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

to several places, but it's still not records.

any idea?

Comment: Simply - you cannot use Sensor API under lock screen. [Similar question was posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155641/track-accelerometer-under-lock-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do anythink while the phone is locked, apart from services (such as Facebook notifications), but even those have a minimum interval.

Comment: Are you 100% sure in this?
like for a fitness app, i must have the user to keep the screen unlocked while does exercises or so (just an example)

Comment: If you're making a fitness app, why would it be any good if the phone would lock itself? You just keep the screen awake. If you're making a running app though, you can make a service to track the GPS coordinates every x minutes.

Comment: for example you dont run with your telephone in your hand, you always place it in your pocked, with a locked screen,
but yes, unfortunatelly i cant get data while its locked

Comment: @user3378002 This answer is mostly wrong - you can do many things under lock screen (with disabled idle detection), but you cannot use Sensor API as [Caution at the first screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202968(v=vs.105).aspx) says.

Comment: yes, i know, but, for me the accelerometer is really can't run while the screen is locked (sadly ).